# Using Shims On Sloped Floors

Tags: flooring

My condo’s floors are sloped by 4” front to back. Very noticeable in the back 1/4.
How can I determine the size of a shim needed?  I have a concrete subfloor.  My idea is to use shims and plywood to make it as level as possible.  I’m in Decatur, Ga.

Comment: What distance are we talking about?  Possible a 4 inch slope is showing other problems with the building.

Comment: If you’re really out 4” in the space of a normal room, you’ve got problems bigger than we can fix. Get professionals in to assess the underlying cause.

Answer (score 2):

You have a concrete subfloor that was poured and not leveled. It has high spots and low spots that can give the appearance of a drastic pitch. The reality of raising flooring to make up a 4" difference has other consequences. Door heights will be drastically reduced, possible fitment issues for appliances in a kitchen, plumbing drain issues, etc.  You didn't indicate if you were attempting a complete home remodel or just trying to level off the subfloor for installing new finished flooring. If it's the latter, concrete leveling compound can be poured to make the floor smooth for your new flooring without raising an amount that will cause many other issues. As crip659 said 4" indicates a serious building problem.

Answer (score 1):

Pull a chalk line or thin wire or string from where the floor starts to slope to the maximum slope. Hang a string bubble level from the middle of the string, see picture below from Amazon. Now measure the distances from the floor to the level string in many places noting the measurements. Those will be your shim heights minus the flooring. You might want to cut "joists" to match the slope instead of shims.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A laser level, a tape measure, and a ruler, or a variety of more complicated methods that amount to the same thing done differently.

Plot a grid, and set your level on the line of each proposed sleeper shim.

Lay the tape measure out from your reference wall, write down the ruler measurements of the laser height as frequently as you plant to be fiddly about the cutting (2 ft, 1 ft, 6 inches... and then transfer those measurements to the sleeper/shim you'll cut to fit that spot. You'll need a reference point so all the measurements are referring to the same level.

Comment: The most foolproof, accurate and cheapest method is a **water level**.   A clear plastic hose with water in it.  The water levels at the ends of the hose will always be exactly the same.

Comment: I don't agree. They are fussy, messy, and prone to error - all it takes is a bubble in the tube and they are out of whack.